# NSTable doesn't register scroll, view does

Tags: objective-c, macos, appkit

I have an `NSTableView` in my app, that's being set up as follows:

```
self.tableContainer = [[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
self.tableContainer.backgroundColor = [NSColor darkBackgroundColor];
self.setsTable = [[NSTableView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
self.setsTable.backgroundColor = [NSColor darkBackgroundColor];
NSTableColumn *column1 = [[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"Col1"];
[column1 setWidth:self.setsTable.frame.size.width];
[self.setsTable setHeaderView:nil];
[self.setsTable addTableColumn:column1];
[self.setsTable setDelegate:self];
[self.setsTable setDataSource:self];
[self.setsTable reloadData];
[self.tableContainer setDocumentView:self.setsTable];
[self.tableContainer setHasVerticalScroller:YES];
[self.view addSubview:self.tableContainer];
```

However, what happens when I scroll is that the `NSScrollView` will register the scroll and the `NSTableView` won't. You can see it in the gif below:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't see the relationship between NSScrollView and NSTableView since you don't add the table to your scroll view.

Comment: `setDocumentView` adds the table to the scroll view.

Comment: I tested your code and it works. What do you mean by 'will register the scroll'?

Comment: @Willeke I added a gif showing the behaviour. You can clearly see that the last cut-off cell remains cut-off.

Comment: Is the table view view based? Show us your implementation of  `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:`.

Comment: Your view hierarchy is: scrollview --> tableView. It should (must) be scrollview --> clipView --> tableView.

Comment: `setDocumentView` adds the table view to the clipview.